# Joomla: click menu see relevant category

Tags: joomla, categories

Is there a way in Joomla that when i click on menu, i see list of categories available in that menu. And when i click on a category, i see items inside it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about dropdown menus....In case you need dropdown menu you can you [this Drop Down menu module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/6731)
It will work